# Nested resource check

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a Rails form, where is reported the user and the skills of the user (the association is many to many) so I use accepted_nested resource in the form
Everything works okkey, the user have the chance to create a new skill and associate themself to it.
The problem is that if a skill with the same name already exists, I don't want that one more skill with the same name is created, I just want an association with the user and the already existing skill.
Do I have to leave the nested resource approach and performing some controls in the controller in order to choose if create or just associate the skill ?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rails' find_or_create_by method to find or create the skill by whatever criteria you choose. Then add that to the user's skill collection. I don't know what your code looks like, but something like this:

```
@skill = Skill.find_or_create_by_name(params[:skill][:name])
@user.skills << @skill
```

Comment: It would be better to put this sort of thing into a model method rather than the controller, BTW.